(COMPLETED) Public Site API Maintenance -Wed, November 20, 2024, 10:00 PM-11:00 PM EST (Thurs, November 21, 03:00 UTC - Thurs, November 21, 04:00 UTC)
Update: API maintenance has been completed.

We will be doing a quick failover test of api.stackexchange.com on Wednesday, November 20, 2024, 10:00 PM-11:00 PM EST (Thursday, November 21, 03:00 UTC - Thursday, November 21, 04:00 UTC).
During this time, the public API will only allow GET routes. PUT, POST, and DELETE routes will be unavailable as the API will be in read-only mode. We expect this failover test to only last 30 minutes.
I'll update this post when the maintenance has been completed.
